# How can I suppress all output from a command using Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, echo

I have a Bash script that runs a program with parameters.  That program outputs some status (doing this, doing that...). There isn't any option for this program to be quiet. How can I prevent the script from displaying anything?

I am looking for something like Windows' ["echo off"](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html).

Answer (score 664, accepted):

The following sends standard output to the null device (bit bucket).

```
scriptname >/dev/null
```

And if you also want error messages to be sent there, use one of (the first may not work in all shells):

```
scriptname &>/dev/null
scriptname >/dev/null 2>&1
scriptname >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

And, if you want to record the messages, but not see them, replace `/dev/null` with an actual file, such as:

```
scriptname &>scriptname.out
```

For completeness, under Windows cmd.exe (where "nul" is the equivalent of "/dev/null"), it is:

```
scriptname >nul 2>nul
```

Comment: Note that '&>' is peculiar to bash (and maybe C shells); Korn and Bourne shells require 2> /dev/null or 2>&1 (to send stderr to the same place as stdout). The Korn shell seems to interpret '&>' as "run the stuff up to & in background, then do the i/o redirection on an empty command".

Comment: Note that some commands write directly to the terminal device rather than to standard output/error. To test, put `echo foo > $(tty)` in a script and run `./test.sh &> /dev/null` - The output is still printed to the terminal. Of course this is not a problem if you're writing a script which uses no such commands.

Comment: @l0b0, is there a way to make the script's (or any other program's) tty different so that all output is redirected regardless of your example? I know screen and script can do something like that but both are finicky and vary from *nix to *nix.

Comment: @yang `/dev/null` exists in Cygwin, you don't need to use `nul`.

Answer (score 58):

Something like

```
script > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This will prevent standard output *and* error output, redirecting them both to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Also achieved with just &> if you want to save some typing ;)

Comment: Even though I'm adding this to my gs (GhostScript) command, it still prints out  **** Warning: File has a corrupted %%EOF marker, or garbage after %%EOF. Any advice?

Comment: This does not run the process on unix systems , I had to do `2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 20):

An alternative that may fit in some situations is to assign the result of a command to a variable:

```
$ DUMMY=$( grep root /etc/passwd 2>&1 )
$ echo $?
0
$ DUMMY=$( grep r00t /etc/passwd 2>&1 )
$ echo $?
1
```

Since Bash and other POSIX commandline interpreters does not consider variable assignments as a command, the present command's return code is respected.

**Note:** assignement with the `typeset` or `declare` keyword is considered as a command, so the evaluated return code in case is the assignement itself and not the command executed in the sub-shell:

```
$ declare DUMMY=$( grep r00t /etc/passwd 2>&1 )
$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 18):

Try

```
: $(yourcommand)
```

`:` is short for "do nothing".

`$()` is just your command.

Comment: Very interesting but there is a limitation: the returned status code is always `0` (success). Let's see an example using command `false` that always returns `1` (failure). For instance `( echo foo | tee file ; false ) && echo bar` displays `foo`. Using your trick to suppress the output: `( : $(echo foo | tee file ; false) ) && echo bar`. But it displays `bar` meaning the return status code is `0` (this is not the returned status code from `false`). Please update your answer providing this limitation. Cheers

Comment: @olibre, what about `DUMMY=$(yourcommand)`? It do not have the limitation you have mentioned. :)

Comment: @semente Perfect: The command `DUMMY=$( echo foo | tee file ; false ) && echo bar` does not display anything.  And the command `DUMMY=$( echo foo | tee file ; true ) && echo bar` displays `bar`. Let me know if your provide an answer to upvote it ;-) Cheers

Comment: An alternative is `command | :` which maybe easier to type

Answer (score 8):

Like [andynormancx' post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617182/how-can-i-suppress-all-output-from-a-command-using-bash/617184#617184), use this (if you're working in an Unix environment):

```
scriptname > /dev/null
```

Or you can use this (if you're working in a Windows environment):

```
scriptname > nul
```

Comment: You can actually do better than that in the Windows shell. If instead you use "scriptname > nul" then you won't even have a file to delete, as "nul" is the Windows equivalent of /dev/null.

Comment: @andynormancx: That's what I hate about the Windows file system layout. It "reserves" filenames like NUL, COM1, LPT1, CON, etc, no matter what directory you're in (even if you're in a file-system that can have those filenames, like in network shares).

Comment: I don't think I've actually used NUL since DOS 5.x, had a sudden flash of remembrance when I saw this answer ;)

Comment: In case you used `> nul` on Windows with cygwin or git bash and now you are stuck with a `nul` file that can't be deleted, please do give a try to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883481/delete-a-file-named-nul-on-windows), it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

This is another option

```
scriptname |& :
```

Comment: I think is probably the best one, considering it doesn't require buffering the output of the command in memory.

Comment: This is the more clever solution.

Comment: Why is this "clever"? `:` discards its input, so it works like `/dev/null`, but you are needlessly creating a pipe where none is necessary or useful.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this example from **[The Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)**:

> **3.6 Sample: stderr and stdout 2 file**
>
> This will place every output of a program to a file. This is suitable sometimes for cron entries, if you want a command to pass in absolute silence.
>
> ```
>      rm -f $(find / -name core) &> /dev/null
> ```

That said, you can use this simple redirection:

```
/path/to/command &>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running a command in the background and want to suppress its output, the syntax is the following:

`(my_command > /dev/null &)`
or
`(my_command > /dev/null 2>&1 &)`

Comment: can you explain what is the difference between the two?

Comment: @osbm: the difference is the `2>&1` part, which is redirection of stderr to stdout. The first command will only suppress stdout but not stderr; the 2nd will suppress both.

Comment: got it, thank you

Comment: this made my day, the compiller was giving info. messages even when i routed > /dev/null this 2>&1 helped me removing redundant entries in output

Answer (score 1):

In your script you can add the following to the lines that you know are going to give an output:

```
some_code 2>>/dev/null
```

Or else you can also try

```
some_code >>/dev/null
```

Comment: never saw >> to /dev/null.. out of curiosity.. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Is it suppressing all output?

Comment: Why the double ">" (`>>`)?

Comment: Using >> to null is unnecessary and somewhat incorrect, but in this case, harmless.

Answer (score 1):

`>&-` closes the filedescriptor without even redirecting to /dev/null

`foo 2>&- >&-`

Can close stdin too
`foo 2>&- >&- <&-`