# How to silence output in a Bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a program that outputs to stdout and would like to silence that output in a Bash script while piping to a file.

For example, running the program will output:

```
% myprogram
% WELCOME TO MY PROGRAM
% Done.
```

I want the following script to not output anything to the terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
myprogram > sample.s
```

Comment: From what I recall, redirecting output to a file causes it to not be echoed to the terminal. What's not working for you?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/41964/how-to-hide-the-output-of-a-shell-application-in-linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress all output from a command using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617182/how-to-suppress-all-output-from-a-command-using-bash)

Answer (score 229):

If it outputs to stderr as well you'll want to silence that. You can do that by redirecting file descriptor 2:

```
# Send stdout to out.log, stderr to err.log
myprogram > out.log 2> err.log

# Send both stdout and stderr to out.log
myprogram &> out.log      # New bash syntax
myprogram > out.log 2>&1  # Older sh syntax

# Log output, hide errors.
myprogram > out.log 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: The "&>" line is a shorter version of what I just posted. I haven't come across that shortcut before. Upvoting.

Comment: `&>` is a lot older than bash 4.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Can you possibly link the changelog documenting `&>`s introduction? :o

Comment: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES#n2208 indicates that `>>&` was introduced in 4.0. There is no mention of `&>` but the CHANGES only go back to 2.0 so I think that means it was already in 1.x.

Comment: `git blame` on `redir.c` points to a 1998 commit for the oldest occurrence still in the current code base.

Answer (score 95):

### Redirect stderr to stdout

This will redirect the stderr (which is descriptor 2) to the file descriptor 1 which is the the stdout.

```sh
2>&1
```

### Redirect stdout  to File

Now when perform this you are redirecting the stdout to the file `sample.s`

```sh
myprogram > sample.s
```

### Redirect stderr and stdout to File

Combining the two commands will result in redirecting both stderr and stdout to sample.s

```sh
myprogram > sample.s 2>&1
```

### Redirect stderr and stdout to /dev/null

Redirect to `/dev/null` if you want to completely silent your application.

```sh
myprogram >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: The last one is missing a redirection operator; it should be `myprogram >/dev/null 2>&1` (notice the wedge before `/dev/null` and the order of the redirections).

Comment: wouldn't `myprogram &>/dev/null` be enough?

Answer (score 54):

> Following only works with `bash` (`/bin/bash`) or similar (like `zsh`), is not working with `sh` (`/bin/sh`).

All output:

```
scriptname &>/dev/null
```

Portable:

```
scriptname >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Portable:

```
scriptname >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It actually creates a file named `-` and `&>` is a non-portable bourne shell extension.

Comment: The portable equivalent `echo moo 1>&-` produces an error because file descriptor 1 is closed: `-bash: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor`

Answer (score 15):

If you are still struggling to find an answer, specially if you produced a file for the output, and you prefer a clear alternative:

`echo "hi" | grep "use this hack to hide the oputut :) "`

Comment: Interesting hack... upvoting for cleverness ^_^

Answer (score 12):

If you want STDOUT and STDERR both [everything], then the simplest way is:

```
#!/bin/bash
myprogram >& sample.s
```

then run it like `./script`, and you will get no output to your terminal. :)

the ">&" means STDERR and STDOUT. the `&` also works the same way with a pipe: `./script |& sed`
that will send everything to sed

Comment: man bash (under "Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error") says &> and >& are equivalent but the first (&>) is preferred.
However |& is the only way to do this for pipes.

Comment: @John No, the portable way for pipes is `a 2>&1 | b 2>&1 | c`

Answer (score 6):

Try with:

```
myprogram &>/dev/null
```

to get no output

Answer (score 2):

### Useful variations:

---

- Get only the **STDERR** in a file, while hiding any **STDOUT** even if the
  program to hide isn't existing at all. (does not ever hang):

  ```
  stty -echo && ./programMightNotExist 2> errors.log && stty echo
  ```

---

- Detach completely and silence everything, even killing the parent
  script won't abort `./prog` (Does behave just like `nohup`):

  ```
  ./prog </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
  ```

---

- [`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) can be used as well to fully detach, as follow:

  ```
  nohup ./prog &
  ```

  A log file `nohup.out` will be created aside of the script, use `tail -f nohup.out` to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer is related to the question "How to turn off echo while executing a shell script Linux" which was in turn marked as duplicated to this one.

To actually turn off the echo the command is:

> stty -echo

(this is, for instance; when you want to enter a password and you don't want it to be readable. Remember to turn echo on at the end of your script, otherwise the person that runs your script won't see what he/she types in from then on. To turn echo on run:

> stty echo

Answer (score -1):

For output **only on error**:

> [so](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/so) [command]

[image: Logo]