# How to disable emacs console messages

Tags: emacs

When I open emacs from a terminal with the emacs& command, I get a lot of debug messages on that terminal. This obscures what I was doing before. Is there a way of suppressing debug message output to the terminal?

Thanks!

Comment: It should work in linux `emacs& &>/dev/null`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292847/how-to-silent-output-in-a-bash-script

Answer (score 1):

Redirect stderr to `/dev/null`.

```
emacs 2>/dev/null& command
```

This alias should to the trick, just put in in .bashrc or your shells rc file.

```
alias emacs="emacs 2>/dev/null"
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS, but you seem to be on Linux.
If it is the case, create a launcher icon, eg for [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220512/how-can-i-create-launcher-icon-for-phpstorm).

This way the desktop environment, like Gnome or KDE, starts the process instead of the terminal, and messages do not appear.