# Return the bash file code at the end of execution in php

Tags: php, bash

I have used a bash file in a php file. (Require/Include) After that when i want to run the bash file, but not want code will be returned. Result is coming at the end. But the unnecessary codes are coming.

```
<?php
require_once("shapemorph");
ob_start();
$imageFile2 = 'one-car.jpg';
$imageFile1 = 'two-car.jpg';
shell_exec('./shapemorph -d 10 -p 100 -r "73,56 57,68" '.$imageFile2.' '.$imageFile2.' testfy.gif');
ob_end_flush();
exit;
?>
```

I have used ob_start() for that also. But still the codes are coming.

I do not want the code to be returned.

Comment: I should work if you insert it right in the bashfile

Comment: You could look at this thread too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292847/how-to-silence-output-in-a-bash-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Just return them to /dev/null if your using Linux

Comment: Thanks for reply. But this code should work in server. I am unknown about the server configuration.

Comment: you could also redirect the output in a file and remove it as last operation of your script like : `myscript >> trash.txt`

Comment: Are you telling in the bash file ?

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)