# Is it possible to suppress NPM's echo of the commands it is running?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I've got a bash script that starts up a server and then runs some functional tests. It's got to happen in one script, so I'm running the server in the background. This all happens via 2 npm commands: `start:nolog` and `test:functional`.

All good. But there's a lot of cruft in the output that I don't care about:

```
✗ ./functional-tests/runInPipeline.sh

(... "good" output here)

> @co/foo@2.2.10 pretest:functional /Users/jcol53/Documents/work/foo
> curl 'http://localhost:3000/foo' -s -f -o /dev/null || (echo 'Website must be running locally for functional tests.' && exit 1)


> @co/foo@2.2.10 test:functional /Users/jcol53/Documents/work/foo
> npm run --prefix functional-tests test:dev:chromeff


> @co/foo-functional-tests@1.0.0 test:dev:chromeff /Users/jcol53/Documents/work/foo/functional-tests
> testcafe chrome:headless,firefox:headless ./tests/**.test.js  -r junit:reports/functional-test.junit.xml -r html:reports/functional-test.html --skip-js-errors
```

That's a lot of lines that I don't need there. Can I suppress the `@co/foo-functional-tests` etc lines? They aren't telling me anything worthwhile...

`npm run -s` kills all output from the command, which is not what I'm looking for.

This is probably not possible but that's OK, I'm curious, maybe I missed something...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292847/how-to-silence-output-in-a-bash-script

Comment: I need the output of the npm commands though, I'm just curious if I can remove all those lines prefixed with `> ` above

Comment: Is there a pattern to the kind of lines you want to suppress? Or a pattern to the lines you actually want.

Comment: You're not missing anything as far as I can tell. If the `--silent | -s` option doesn't achieve the desired result you'll just have to accept that [npm run-scripts are noisy](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8821).

Comment: wow, that's an old debate; guess this ship has sailed in the opposite direction of what I want :/

Comment: You might want to try adding one more npm script in _package.js_ that invokes both `start:nolog` and `test:functional` using `npm run` command - and include the `-s` option with both them. For instance: `"scripts": { "both": "npm run start:nolog -s && npm run test:functional -s" }, ...` - Then execute `npm run both` via your ClI. This should reduce _some_ of npm's verbosity, i.e. less `> @co/foo@2.2.10....`) and keep  output of the npm commands - inc. errors.

Comment: Just as surprised with you how this hasn't been addressed properly yet. Any idea if `yarn` also does this or does it produce a cleaner output without echoing the command back to us.

Comment: Yarn's install output is much cleaner.

Comment: For me, `npm --silent run <script-alias>` works. Also, `yarn --silent run <script-alias>` works.

Comment: `npm run --slient run <script-alias` IS NOT WORKING. I've been resolved with grep command like this: `npm run something-script | grep -v "^>"`

Comment: @cyan-kinesin did you know there's a typo in that?

Comment: @cyan-kinesin but that's a good idea, want to post it as an answer?

Comment: @jcollum OK, I have reproduced this issue and writing my opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced this issue with [github repository](https://github.com/j1i-ian/stackoverflow-test-npm-echo-in-pipeline) with github actions for observation.

npm silent option `-s` is removing verbose texts except output of ifself

but this option has only worked when that is passed directly

***Solution 1. Pass `-s` directly***

Let's take a npm sample script

here are two scripts.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
npm pkg set scripts.myecho="echo sample"
npm pkg set scripts.silent_myecho="npm run -s myecho"
```

results are:

```bash
$ npm run myecho # verbose

> stackoverflow-test-npm-echo-in-pipeline@1.0.0 myecho
> echo sample

sample

$ npm run silent_myecho  # verbose

> stackoverflow-test-npm-echo-in-pipeline@1.0.0 silent_myecho
> npm run -s myecho

sample

$ npm run -s myecho # not verbose
sample

$ npm run -s silent_myecho # not verbose
sample
```

it is same result on [github actions](https://github.com/j1i-ian/stackoverflow-test-npm-echo-in-pipeline/actions/runs/4282730998/jobs/7457374437).

***Solution 2. Filter with invert grep***

Or you can filter npm outputs grep with invert option

`npm run myecho | grep -v "^>"` # use regex for matching only starting carrots

then, you can remove new lines with tr like this:

`npm run myecho | grep -v "^>" | tr -d '\n'`

maybe it is useful when you want to extract but cannot pass silent option like `npm test`.

Comment: Good write up 

Comment: @jcollum I'm delightful it is helpful !