# Could I run a Rails Server and type commands to my Rails Project through terminal at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, rake, localhost

I'm running my rails server through the terminal by typing `rails server`. After this, it seems the terminal is unavailable for further commands, but I would like to run some tests by typing `rake test` without having to `CTRL + C` out of my server, then `rake test`, and finally turning my server back on with `rails server`. Is there common solution for this?

Comment: You can run commands in another terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also recommend using several tabs or even a terminal multiplexer such as [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/). However you could very well send the server process to the background with

```
rails s &
```

This will most likely clutter up your terminal with lots of log output unless you suppress the output as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617182/with-bash-scripting-how-can-i-suppress-all-output-from-a-command). You can foreground the process by typing

```
fg
```

and even look at the logs in a different terminal by typing something along the lines of

```
tail -f log/development.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your terminal you can use File->new tab, or maj+ctrl+t to pen a new tab.
Personally i have one tab for the server, one for the tests using guard, one for the console and one to have an actual shell.