# How to delete NUL.LST file?

Tags: oracle, batch-file, dos

I believe that when I passed "NUL" as the Oracle sqlplus spool file name, that Oracle created the NUL.LST file.

However, I have not yet found any way to delete this file? Any suggestions?

```
M:>dir *.lst
 Volume in drive M is D
 Volume Serial Number is 904D-B54E

 Directory of M:\DW_Extract\Prod

2014-04-03  15:59               622 NUL.LST
```

Comment: `host delete NUL.LST` should delete it from `SQL*plus`

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/282194/how-do-i-remove-a-file-named-nul-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

The answer I used is from RealHowTo.

[Delete a file named "NUL" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883481/delete-a-file-named-nul-on-windows) :

```
C:\> rename \\.\C:\..\NUL. deletefile.txt
C:\> del deletefile.txt
```

I did not try sqlplus 'host del'.