# How does nul work when a file called nul exists

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, nul

If nul can never be a file in Windows, what if it a file called "nul" was created in all the directorys using a OS that doesn't have the same rules for nul. Would data be written to nul if for example 'echo 1234>nul' was performed in CMD or would it be discarded?

Comment: The accepted answer helps future visitors to quickly navigate to useful information. In this case I would recommend accepting [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37927677/1889329) instead. Make sure to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as well as [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: There should never, ever be a file named 'NUL'. However, sometimes things happen. In an Oracle environment, I had a file named 'NUL.LST'. 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186852/how-to-delete-nul-lst-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nul is not a reference to a file, it is part of Windows and when >nul is performed, it isn't writing it the the file nul, but instead it's just being ignored

Answer (score 8):

> if for example 'echo 1234>nul' was performed in CMD or would it be discarded?

It would be discarded.

Note the following example which creates a file called `nul` then calls `echo 5678>nul`. The existing file `nul` is not changed.

```
C:\temp>echo 1234>\\?\%cd%\nul

C:\temp>dir /b /a-d
nul

C:\temp>type \\?\%cd%\nul
1234

C:\temp>echo 5678>nul

C:\temp>type \\?\%cd%\nul
1234

C:\temp>del \\?\%cd%\nul

C:\temp>
```

For details about the `\\?\` syntax see [Win32 File Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#win32_file_namespaces).