# using NUL dir on Windows messed up my Git

Tags: node.js, windows, git, fs, dev-null

I had this code running in a Node.js codebase for awhile:

```
if (os.platform() === 'win32') {
    stdout = fs.openSync('NUL', 'a');
```

it put a ghost file ('NUL') on my machine at the root of the project, and I can't git rm it or delete it permanently. Having this file around seems to make git very unreliable; commits don't seem to work completely.

Does anybody know what do with this?

Comment: [Why can't we make CON, PRN,Null folder in windows?](http://superuser.com/q/613313/241386)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a file named "NUL" on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883481/delete-a-file-named-nul-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The good news is: it won't mess up your Git no more.
Because, with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), Git will forbid pathnames that the platform's filesystem cannot represent on MinGW.

See [commit 4dc42c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4dc42c6c1867a52e22f1f04a1a247b5a7538b8af), [commit 98d9b23](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98d9b23e90510c5acafa2ebc9463cc2293f40df0) (21 Dec 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 13432fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13432fc6dd4f9f78d0015611621991693f8fb218), 02 Jan 2020)</sup>

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4dc42c6c1867a52e22f1f04a1a247b5a7538b8af): refuse paths containing reserved names
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> There are a couple of reserved names that cannot be file names on Windows, such as `AUX`, `NUL`, etc.
>   For an almost complete list, see "[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces: 'Naming Conventions'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions)".
>
> If one would try to create a directory named `NUL`, it would actually "succeed", i.e. the call would return success, but nothing would be created.
>
> Worse, even adding a file extension to the reserved name does not make it a valid file name.
>   To understand the rationale behind that behavior, see "[What's the deal with those reserved filenames like `NUL` and `CON`?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031022-00/?p=42073)" from [Raymond Chen](https://twitter.com/ChenCravat).
>
> Let's just disallow them all.

---

Git 2.27 (Q2 2020) fixes another issue with `COM0`.

See [commit 3efc128](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3efc128cd59fefb6aa159548d0cf7666ce5e34a9) (09 Apr 2020), and [commit b6852e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6852e19794245566f7c961a434c56ca3b7a883b) (08 Apr 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit a748f3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a748f3f3dc0adff1d8a83dfc098ed819658998d0) (08 Apr 2020) by [Matthias Aßhauer (`rimrul`)](https://github.com/rimrul).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b3eb70e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3eb70e0f8988dbf36f42e0bea201e2cd71f248e), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6852e19794245566f7c961a434c56ca3b7a883b): do not treat `COM0` as a reserved file name
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> In [4dc42c6c186](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4dc42c6c1867a52e22f1f04a1a247b5a7538b8af) ("`mingw`: refuse paths containing reserved names", 2019-12-21, Git v2.25.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13432fc6dd4f9f78d0015611621991693f8fb218)), we started disallowing file names that are reserved, e.g. `NUL`, `CONOUT$`, etc.
>
> This included `COM<n>` where `<n>` is a digit.
>
> Unfortunately, this includes `COM0` but only `COM1`, ..., `COM9` are reserved, according to the official documentation, `COM0` is mentioned in the "NT Namespaces" section but it is explicitly *omitted* from the list of reserved names: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions
>
> Tests corroborate this: it is totally possible to write a file called `com0.c` on Windows 10, but not `com1.c`.
>
> So let's tighten the code to disallow only the reserved `COM<n>` file names, but to allow `COM0` again.
>
> This fixes [`git-for-windows/git` issue 2470](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2470) "Cannot add file `COM0.c` or checkout branch containing `COM0.c` file".