# How to hide command output in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want to make my Bash scripts more elegant for the end user. How do I hide the output when Bash is executing commands?

For example, when Bash executes

```
yum install nano
```

The following will show up to the user who executed the Bash:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                          | 4.4 MB     00:03
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                        |  18 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                       | 3.8 MB     00:02
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nano.x86_64 0:2.0.9-7.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package         Arch              Version                Repository       Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 nano            x86_64            2.0.9-7.el6            base            436 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 436 k
Installed size: 1.5 M
Downloading Packages:
nano-2.0.9-7.el6.x86_64.rpm                              | 436 kB     00:00
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
Importing GPG key 0xC105B9DE:
 Userid : CentOS-6 Key (CentOS 6 Official Signing Key) <centos-6-key@centos.org>
 Package: centos-release-6-4.el6.centos.10.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
 From   : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : nano-2.0.9-7.el6.x86_64                                      1/1
  Verifying  : nano-2.0.9-7.el6.x86_64                                      1/1

Installed:
  nano.x86_64 0:2.0.9-7.el6

Complete!
```

Now I want to hide this from the user and instead show:

```
    Installing nano ......
```

How can I accomplish this task? I will definitely help to make the script more user friendly. In case an error occurs then it should be shown to the user.

I would like to know how to show same message while a set of commands are being executed.

Comment: `echo "Installing nano ......"; yum install nano &> /dev/null`

Comment: See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617182/with-bash-scripting-how-can-i-suppress-all-output-from-a-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress all output from a command using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617182/how-to-suppress-all-output-from-a-command-using-bash)

Answer (score 326, accepted):

#### Use this.

```
{
  /your/first/command
  /your/second/command
} &> /dev/null
```

#### Explanation

To eliminate output from commands, you have two options:

- Close the output descriptor file, which keeps it from accepting any more input. That looks like this:

  ```
  your_command "Is anybody listening?" >&-
  ```

  Usually, output goes either to file descriptor 1 (stdout) or 2 (stderr). If you close a file descriptor, you'll have to do so for every numbered descriptor, as `&>` (below) is a special BASH syntax incompatible with `>&-`:

  ```
  /your/first/command >&- 2>&-
  ```

  Be careful to note the order: `>&-` [closes stdout](https://blog.apokalyptik.com/2007/10/24/bash-tip-closing-file-descriptors/), which is what you want to do; `&>-` redirects stdout and stderr to a file named `-` (hyphen), which is not what what you want to do. It'll look the same at first, but the latter creates a stray file in your working directory. It's easy to remember: `>&2` redirects stdout to descriptor 2 (stderr), `>&3` redirects stdout to descriptor 3, and `>&-` redirects stdout to a dead end (i.e. it closes stdout).

  Also beware that some commands may not handle a closed file descriptor particularly well ("write error: Bad file descriptor"), which is why the better solution may be to...
- **[Redirect output to `/dev/null`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null)**, which accepts all output and does nothing with it. It looks like this:

  ```
  your_command "Hello?" > /dev/null
  ```

  For output redirection to a file, you can direct both stdout and stderr to the same place very concisely, but only in bash:

  ```
  /your/first/command &> /dev/null
  ```

Finally, to do the same for a number of commands at once, surround the whole thing in curly braces. Bash treats this as [a group of commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping), aggregating the output file descriptors so you can redirect all at once. If you're familiar instead with subshells using `( command1; command2; )` syntax, you'll find the braces behave almost exactly the same way, except that unless you involve them in a pipe the braces will not create a subshell and thus will allow you to set variables inside.

```
{
  /your/first/command
  /your/second/command
} &> /dev/null
```

See the [bash manual on redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) for more details, options, and syntax.

Comment: Hi, I know it's an old question but can the same be done conditionally? Like I want to hide the output under certain condition? I know I can replicate the same part under if-else but is there a better way to do so?

Comment: @UsamaZafar I would do that by setting a variable (["shell parameter"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html)), which you set to either `/dev/null` or `/dev/stdout` (or `/path/to/a/logfile`) conditionally earlier in the script, and then redirecting to that destination by using `&> $output_dest` (or whatever you name it). If you don't want to combine stdout and stderr in that case, you could redirect them separately like `> $output_dest 2> $errors_dest`.

Comment: I have no idea that this was the purpose of the braces.

Answer (score 50):

You can redirect stdout to /dev/null.

`yum install nano > /dev/null`

Or you can redirect both stdout and stderr,

`yum install nano &> /dev/null`.

But if the program has a quiet option, that's even better.

Answer (score 39):

A process normally has two outputs to screen: **stdout** (standard out), and **stderr** (standard error).

Normally informational messages go to `sdout`, and errors and alerts go to `stderr`.

You can turn off `stdout` for a command by doing

```
MyCommand >/dev/null
```

and turn off `stderr` by doing:

```
MyCommand 2>/dev/null
```

If you want **both off**, you can do:

```
MyCommand >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The `2>&1` says send stderr to the same place as stdout.

Comment: The suggestion for suppressing both doesn't work for me. But this does `> /dev/null 2>&1 `

Answer (score 9):

You can redirect the output to `/dev/null`. For more info regarding /dev/null read this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null).

You can hide the output of a comand in the following ways :

```
echo -n "Installing nano ......"; yum install nano > /dev/null; echo " done.";
```

Redirect the standard output to `/dev/null`, but not the standard error. This will show the errors occurring during the installation, for example if `yum` cannot find a package.

```
echo -n "Installing nano ......"; yum install nano &> /dev/null; echo " done.";
```

While this code will not show anything in the terminal since both standard error  and standard output are redirected and thus nullified to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Great share ....dude can you show me how to output the same message only once for a set of commands

Answer (score 6):

`>/dev/null 2>&1` will mute both `stdout` and `stderr`

```
yum install nano >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not use bash in this case to get rid of the output. Yum does have an option `-q` which suppresses the output.

You'll most certainly also want to use `-y`

```
echo "Installing nano..."
yum -y -q install nano
```

To see all the options for yum, use `man yum`.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed yum had one since apt-get used -qq as well to suppress. This was helpful for what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it by assigning its output to a variable, this is particularly useful when you don't have `/dev/null`.

Yes, I came across a situation when I can't use `/dev/null`.

The solution I found was to assign the output to a variable which I will never use there after:

```sh
hide_output=$([[ -d /proc ]] && [[ mountpoint -q /proc ]] && umount -l /proc)
```

Answer (score 0):

This:
`command > /dev/null`
Or this: (to suppress errors as well)
`command > /dev/null 2>&1`

Similar to lots of other answers but they didn't work for me with `2>` being in front of dev/null.

Answer (score -1):

```
.SILENT:
```

Type  " .SILENT: " in the beginning of your script without colons.

Comment: why do you write the colon in the answer if you don't need it? Or is it quotation marks you are referring to?

Comment: This syntax is for a Makefile and is not for bash or any other scripting language I am aware of.  Makefiles are not scripts.