# Prevent packer printing output for certain inline scripts?

Tags: packer

I am running a bunch of packer scripts, but some of them generate too much output for logs and it's getting really annoying. Is there any way I can change my json file so that I can disable output for one of these shell scripts in packer?

One example of my packer shell script calls that I'd like silenced:

```
{
    "type": "shell",
    "scripts": [
        "scripts/yum_install_and_update"
        "scripts/do_magic"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packer doesn't natively support this, but if you can modify the scripts you could have them [internally suppress the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062778/how-to-hide-command-output-in-bash?lq=1).