# shell - How to hide output

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to hide the output of a command in the shell, but I still want to use the output in a variable:
I am using this:

```
recmake=$(type -t cmake)
```

But I don't want an output in the shell. Only in the variable.

How can I do this.

Nils

Comment: Try that -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062778/how-to-hide-command-output-in-bash @nils-bergmann

Comment: If i would do this like in the post, he will also not save the output in the variable.

Comment: @NilsBergmann the example provided should not generate output except maybe on the standard error. could you elaborate and provide that output wich you would like to hide.

Comment: It should hide every output. With `recmake=$(type -t cmake)` I only want to get the output from the command but the user should not see the output.

Comment: @NilsBergmann: But which output do you get when executing `recmake=$(type -t cmake)`? I don't get any output from it. So I don't really understand what you want to hide...

Answer (score 2):

You could add your code `recmake=$(type -t cmake)` to your `.bashrc` file and then load the variables like this: `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Hi @洋葱头, the **rec=``cmdline```** is doing the same thing as the `$(cmdline)`...

Comment: @AndyK, oh okay, I didn't know that. But what's the problem with `$(cmdline)` then? It doesn't print output to the shell, right?

Comment: `OP` is unclear about what he wants. Probably, not have the output of his shell script is what he is looking at. Therefore the solution I gave him

Comment: I only want to have one script. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following, put everything inside of a bash script,`nameofyourscript`, and run it?

```
#!/bin/sh
recmake=$(type -t cmake)
echo $recmake
```

Then you do `chmod +x nameofyourscript` and `./nameofyourscript`

Comment: Read the question carefully. The op says - `But I don't want an output in the shell. Only in the variable.` If this is not clear to you ask them to clarify.

Comment: Hi @sjsam my solution e.g putting everything within a script and running it, will not give output in the shell to OP

Comment: What difference would it make if you don't spawn a new shell? The op should rephrase the question so that it will make some sense.