# Run Shell scripts without having messages

Tags: shell

I successfully run my shell script on background by the following command:

```
./MyShell.sh &
```

However, there are some useless warnings and messages which appear on my screen. I have used the following command to prevent messages from showing up but all messages appears on screen yet.

```
./MyShell.sh & 2> /dev/null
```

What should I do?

Comment: Move the `&` to the end of the line; after the `2> /dev/null`.

Comment: Right -- `&` is a separator; everything to the right of it is a different command.

Comment: I even moved & to the end of line but all messages appears yet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062778/how-to-hide-command-output-in-bash duplicate?

Comment: `./MyShell.sh  &> /dev/null &` will redirect **both** stdout and stderr