# How to silence the verbose rvm log in Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, rvm

The thing is I'm loading RVM in Jenkins as a function due to bash "not a login" protection. That however outputs the whole RVM configuration to my log => first 8000 lines of log are useless to me.

Is there a way to tell Jenkins CI to silence (not to log) part of the bash script?

something like this

```
# silence begins
echo "this should not log
# silence end

echo 'this should log'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about suppress bash output instead of Jenkins?
I mean is this approach works good for you:

```
# silence begin
echo "this should not log" > /dev/null
# silence end

echo 'this should log'
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617182/with-bash-scripting-how-can-i-suppress-all-output-from-a-command) looks like related to my answer.

**update by Equivalent8:**

this works, and for my situation I needed to use `>&` :

```
# RVM setting
source ~/.bashrc           >& /dev/null # load bashrc conf
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm  >& /dev/null # standard RVM code
type rvm | head -1                      # ensule rvm is is function mode   
rvm use 2.1.2@my_project   >& /dev/null # use ruby version
```