# How to hide output error messages from terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal

I am writing some script in bash.I don't want to output anything(like error messages when I compile .c file)in terminal.
Please explain your answer as I am beginneer to bash and terminal.

Comment: pipe stderr to /dev/null

Comment: gcc ....... myprogram.c 2>/dev/null

Comment: Look for "shell redirection" at internet sources.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617182/with-bash-scripting-how-can-i-suppress-all-output-from-a-command