# Redirect stderr to /dev/null

Tags: linux, grep

I am using the following command on a Unix server:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -li 'needle'
```

Since `grep -R` is not available, I have to use this [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix))/[xargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) solution. Every time a file cannot be opened, `grep` tells me this:

> grep: can't open "foo.txt"

I want to get rid of this message, so I tried to redirect stderr to `/dev/null`, but somehow this is not working.

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -li 'needle' 2>/dev/null
```

I want to preserve stdout (i.e. write the results to the console), and only hide these grep error messages. Instead of `2>`, I also tried `&>`, but this also did not work. How can I fix this?

Comment: What kind of shell are you using?

Comment: Literally pages of answers: [Redirect stderr to /dev/null site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=Redirect+stderr+to+%2Fdev%2Fnull+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: Yes, but that is too unspecific. It is better to find a candidate for a canonical question and point to that (and vote or flag this as a duplicate).

Comment: Related (though that is all output), from 2009: *[How can I suppress all output from a command using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617182)*

Answer (score 192, accepted):

In order to [redirect](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) stderr to /dev/null use:

```
some_cmd 2>/dev/null
```

You don't need `xargs` here. (And you don't want it! since it performs word splitting)

Use find's exec option:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -li needle {} +
```

To suppress the error messages use the `-s` option of `grep`:

From `man grep`:

> -s, --no-messages
>                 Suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.

which gives you:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -lis needle {} +
```

Comment: Thank you @hek2mgl that solution works perfectly :) All the grep warnings are gone (regardless whether or not I use the -s flag). Also didn't know about the `-exec` possiblity.

Answer (score 24):

Just move the redirection to the first command, i.e.

```
find ... 2>/dev/null | xargs ...
```

Or you can enclose everything in parenthesis:

```
(find ... | xargs ...) 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you, but this also does not work :S

    (find . -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -li 'needle') 2>/dev/null
    Badly placed ()'s.
    find . -type f -name "*.txt" 2>/dev/null | xargs grep -li 'needle'
    Ambiguous output redirect.