# Redirect only stderr to /dev/null while redirecting stdout to a file (zsh)

Tags: zsh, stderr, dev-null

I have a command `cmd` that I want to use in a zsh script in the form:

```
cmd -opt val > info.txt
```

but I want to redirect stderr from that one line to `/dev/null`.

Evidently the following does *not* work:

```
cmd -opt val > info.txt > /dev/null
```

How to do it?

**Added:** Note that I do *not* want any regular output written to the terminal; all regular output should be written into the specified file `info.txt`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect stderr to /dev/null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758736/redirect-stderr-to-dev-null)

Comment: In a Bourne-family shell such as `zsh`, you redirect `stderr` by redirecting file descriptor 2 (as opposed to 1 for `stdout`, which is the default for output-redirecting operators).  You will find many answers and examples by searching for "redirect stderr".  In short, however, use `2>` instead of `>`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: NO, using `cmd -opt val 2> info.txt` does *not* do it: while it does send `stderr` to `/dev/null`, it also now sends `stdout` to the terminal, which I do *not* want! I want all normal output from `cmd -opt val` to be written to the file `info.txt` and redirect only any error messages to `/dev/null`.

Comment: What does do what I want is `(cmd -opt val > info.txt) 2> /dev/null`.

Comment: @murray That's not what John Bollinger is suggesting. In your last comment, the subshell is unnecessary.

Comment: As I said, @murray, you redirect *`stderr`* via `2>`. This is independent of redirecting `stdout`, which you seemed already to know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` and `2>` are independent and can appear in the same command.

```
cmd -opt val > info.txt 2> /dev/null
```

Standard output is redirected to `info.txt`, and standard error is redirected to `/dev/null`.