# Streamlink progress bar

Tags: python, bash, stream, stdout, streamlink

I want to download stream when its on and using streamlink in bash script. But when stream starts the progress bar is begin print in stdout. I would like to know how to turn it print off?

```
--logfile "FILE"
```

helping with other type of logs but not with the download, progress bar anyway printed in console
I mean this kind of print:

```
[download][.._2023-01-10_23-25-53.ts] Written 155.8 MB (8m4s @ 394.4 KB/s)
```

```
quality="1080p,best"
dir="/home/artem/writer/"
while true
do
datetime=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)_$(date +%k-%M-%S)
echo "$datetime" >> /home/artem/writer/"${name} log"
file="${name}_$datetime.ts"
streamlink --hls-segment-threads 3 $link $quality -o "$dir$file" --logfile "${name} log"
echo " " >> /home/artem/writer/"${name} log"
sleep 30
done
```

My bash script code ^^ (sry don't want to show link)

I did try --no-progress option i find it somewhere in google but its not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Since a python program is involve? You could try redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` see [Redirect-Stderr-to-Stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-bash) or [stderr to /dev/null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758736/redirect-stderr-to-dev-null)