# Ansible: prevent shell command output from landing in log file

Tags: logging, ansible

I'm trying to get a list of hosts by listing a dynamic inventory through a shell task into a file. And the content appears in the ansible log file, although the stdout is here redirected to a file:

```yaml
- name: get the host list
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: ansible-inventory --list -i {{ dyn_inventory }} > {{ host_list_file }}
  register: list_hosts_cmd
```

This json is *huge* and the log file is becoming unreadable. I want to log just the basic info - the attempt to read and the number of found hosts and I want to catch errors (so no stderr redirect to /dev/null) and this works, but I don't want the actual content of the file in the log file too.

I have tried to disable logging in that shell task with:

```yaml
  ansible.builtin.shell: | 
    unset ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH
    ansible-inventory --list -i {{ dyn_inventory }} > {{ host_list_file }}
```

But that didn't help.

I really hope I'm missing something trivial here and not really need a new stdout callback for that. Like "selective" callback and then stick a print_action tag to other thousand tasks except for this one. In need an "inverted" action for this, so to say.

The Ansible logging has no special configuration, just the path to the file is set and that's it. No special callbacks, no syslog facilities, nothing.

Comment: [no_log](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html#protecting-sensitive-data-with-no-log) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @VladimirBotka Tried it, no luck. The content of readout redirected to a file lands in the log file anyway.

Comment: Can you specify or describe in more detail what do you understand under log file?

Comment: @TonyAngelino, indeed! IMHO, it's a bug. As a workaround, ask *ansible-inventory* to write the file.

Comment: @U880D Under log file I understand the standard ansible main.log or ansible.log file, the one you can also specify with "log_path" in [default] section of the ansible.cfg file or with ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH environment variable.

Comment: Since I am not able to reproduce the issue, can you provide more details regarding, OS, shell version, Ansible version?

Comment: I added an example of 2.16 ignoring no_log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask *ansible-inventory* to write the file. Then, you can use *command* instead of *shell*.

```yaml
  - command: "ansible-inventory --list --output {{ host_list_file }}"
```

---

Note: [no_log](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html#protecting-sensitive-data-with-no-log) doesn't work as expected

Given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[test]
test_01
test_02
test_03

[test:vars]
ansible_user=admin
ansible_become=yes
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
ansible_perl_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/perl
```

and the play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - command: ansible-inventory --list --output /tmp/ansible.hosts

    - shell: ansible-inventory --list > /tmp/ansible.hosts
      no_log: true
```

gives

```yaml
2023-12-14 18:04:51,225 p=517137 u=admin n=ansible | PLAY [localhost] **********
2023-12-14 18:04:51,266 p=517137 u=admin n=ansible | TASK [command] ************
2023-12-14 18:04:52,202 p=517137 u=admin n=ansible | changed: [localhost]
2023-12-14 18:04:52,205 p=517137 u=admin n=ansible | TASK [shell] **************
2023-12-14 18:04:52,910 p=517189 u=admin n=ansible | {
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "test_01": {
                "ansible_become": "yes",
                "ansible_perl_interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/perl",
                "ansible_python_interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/python3.8",
                "ansible_user": "admin"
            },
            "test_02": {
                "ansible_become": "yes",
                "ansible_perl_interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/perl",
                "ansible_python_interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/python3.8",
                "ansible_user": "admin"
            },
            "test_03": {
                "ansible_become": "yes",
                "ansible_perl_interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/perl",
                "ansible_python_interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/python3.8",
                "ansible_user": "admin"
            }
        }
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped",
            "test"
        ]
    },
    "test": {
        "hosts": [
            "test_01",
            "test_02",
            "test_03"
        ]
    }
}
2023-12-14 18:04:53,003 p=517137 u=admin n=ansible | changed: [localhost]
2023-12-14 18:04:53,008 p=517137 u=admin n=ansible | PLAY RECAP ****************
2023-12-14 18:04:53,009 p=517137 u=admin n=ansible | localhost: ok=2 changed=2 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. Although this workaround did solve my case, there is obviously a problem with redirect to a file.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04LTS with Python3.8 with this effect, but with py 3.11 in venv it seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - shell:
      cmd: ansible-inventory --inventory example.com --list 2> /dev/null > example.com.json
    register: result

  - debug:
      var: result.stdout
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [shell] *******
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******
ok: [localhost] =>
  result.stdout: ''
```

and a log file of

```json
Dec 14 2023 17:00:00 - inventory.yml -  - shell - OK - {"module_args": {"warn": false, "executable": null, "_uses_shell": true, "strip_empty_ends": true, "_raw_params": "ansible-inventory --inventory example.com --list 2> /dev/null > example.com.json", "removes": null, "argv": null, "creates": null, "chdir": null, "stdin_add_newline": true, "stdin": null}} => {"stderr_lines": [], "cmd": "ansible-inventory --inventory example.com --list 2> /dev/null > example.com.json", "end": "2023-12-14 17:00:00.703437", "_ansible_no_log": false, "stdout": "", "changed": true, "start": "2023-12-14 16:00:00.009830", "delta": "0:00:00.693607", "stderr": "", "rc": 0, "stdout_lines": [], "msg": ""}

Dec 14 2023 17:00:00 - inventory.yml -  - debug - OK - {"_ansible_no_log": false, "changed": false, "_ansible_verbose_always": true, "result.stdout": ""}
```

as well the corresponding file output `example.com.json` of

```json
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "test",
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    },
    "test": {
        "hosts": [
            "test1.example.com",
            "test2.example.com",
            "test3.example.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

Please take note that [suppressing `stderr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758736/) was only used to not have deprecation warnings logged.

**Summary**

I **wasn't able to reproduce** an issue with the currently given details and information.