# Creating custom steps in groovy

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

I'm working with jenkins pipeline and have a shared global library. I created several functions that users can use, however the main problem I'm facing is having better output in the Console Output and Blue Ocean:
Is there a way to create in groovy a named block (such as when calling the sh function all the output is contained inside)?
I tried playing around with stages like so:

```
stage('Checkout') {
    checkout scm
    stage('Some Custom Step') {
        // Some custom step logic
    }
}
```

However this approach didn't work.
I know you can create custom steps by writing plugins for Jenkins and then calling the function in your groovy script, I was just wandering if there is a way to write such a thing directly in groovy, say, in my library.

Also is there a way to silence output?

```
sh '<some command with meaningful output>'
sh '<some random output not relevant to the user>' // 
Silence somehow
echo 'step finished successfuly!'
```

Thanks for everyone in advance

Comment: For that you presumably would need to write your own plugin to provide that step. After writing one myself I found it pretty easy to do - if you got some java background..

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know if you can write a step inside pipeline and would like to know that too, but as for silencing the output you can do as mentioned on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617182/with-bash-scripting-how-can-i-suppress-all-output-from-a-command): redirect output to '/dev/null'.

It should be something like

```
sh '<some command with meaningful output>'
sh '<some random output not relevant to the user> > dev/null'
```