# Suppressing output from xnee

Tags: bash, unix

I have the following command:

```
cnee -replay -f $filename.xns -sk q -ns
```

I want to suppress all output from xnee when this runs.  I tried changing it to

```
DUMMY=$( cnee -replay -f $filename.xns -sk q -ns )
```

based on the advice I found here: [How to suppress all output from a command using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617182/how-to-suppress-all-output-from-a-command-using-bash/32729736#32729736)

Problem is, I still see this output:

```
Workaround: Creating context on data display instead of control 
            You can ignore this message
Workaround: Creating context on data display instead of control 
            You can ignore this message
NOTIFICATION: If you have problem with Xnee and recording device events: File a bug report including this text.
NOTIFICATION: If you have problem with Xnee and recording device events: File a bug report including this text.
Workaround: Creating context on data display instead of control 
            You can ignore this message
```

Any ideas of ways that a command could still output to the shell in spite of executing it in $() to a variable?

Bash version: GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a common way of handling this is

```
$ your_command &> /dev/null
```

will send both stdin and stderr to black hole.  You can selectively filter stdin or stderr as well.